# How to use recursion on a javascript data structure to lookup and add new data in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, recursion, underscore.js

I have a data structure returned from a database call that looks like this:

```
[{
    "LOCATION_ID": 1001,
    "LOCATIONS": [{
        "LOCATION_ID": 2001,
        "LOCATIONS": [{
            "LOCATION_ID": 2002,
            "LOCATIONS": [{
                "LOCATION_ID": 3002
            }]
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "LOCATION_ID": 5001
}
```

]

I need to iterate recursively through this, get the `LOCATION_ID` and call a different service to return some additional data for each item, then add that to the data structure.

So something like `getMoreData(LOCATION_ID)`, then set `MOREDATA: "MoreDataValues-for-X00X"` for the item, so the resulting structure will look like this.

```
[{
        "LOCATION_ID": 1001,
        "MOREDATA": "MoreDataValues-for-1001",
        "LOCATIONS": [{
            "LOCATION_ID": 2001,
            "MOREDATA": "MoreDataValues-for-2001",
            "LOCATIONS": [{
                "LOCATION_ID": 2002,
                "MOREDATA": "MoreDataValues-for-2002",
                "LOCATIONS": [{
                    "LOCATION_ID": 3002,
                    "MOREDATA": "MoreDataValues-for-3002"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "LOCATION_ID": 5001,
        "MOREDATA": "MoreDataValues-for-5001"
    }
]
```

This is an Angular 2 project (v4), and I'm using UnderscoreJS, but I'm struggling with recursion and can't quite wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way, added comments to help understand

```js
let arr = [{
    "LOCATION_ID": 1001,
    "LOCATIONS": [{
        "LOCATION_ID": 2001,
        "LOCATIONS": [{
            "LOCATION_ID": 2002,
            "LOCATIONS": [{
                "LOCATION_ID": 3002
            }]
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "LOCATION_ID": 5001
}
];
function getMoreData(locationId){
    return "some data for " + locationId;
}

function recursivelyTraverseArr(locations){
    // get an array of locations
    for(let location of locations){
        if(location.LOCATION_ID){
            // if location_id exists add new property
            location.data = getMoreData(location.LOCATION_ID);
        }
        if(location.LOCATIONS){
            // if locations exist recursively call inside
            recursivelyTraverseArr(location.LOCATIONS);
        }
    }
}

recursivelyTraverseArr(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will recursively process all your locations. I've added some console.log statements so you can get a sense of when what happens.

```js
var data = [{
    "LOCATION_ID": 1001,
    "LOCATIONS": [{
        "LOCATION_ID": 2001,
        "LOCATIONS": [{
            "LOCATION_ID": 2002,
            "LOCATIONS": [{
                "LOCATION_ID": 3002
            }]
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "LOCATION_ID": 5001
}];

function processData(data) {
  // Iterate over all the items in the array.
  for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    // Get the item at the current index.
    var item = data[index];
    console.log(`Processing item with ID ${item.LOCATION_ID}`);
    // Check if the item has a LOCATIONS property.
    if (item.LOCATIONS !== undefined) {
      // Process the array stored in the LOCATIONS PROPERTY.
      processData(item.LOCATIONS);
    }
    
    // Set the MORE_DATA property for the current item.
    console.log(`Setting more data for item ${item.LOCATION_ID}`);
    item.MORE_DATA = `More data for ${item.LOCATION_ID}`;
  }
}

processData(data);
console.log(data);
```